# Swift plug-in architecture

Tags: swift, plugins

I'm looking for a way to implement at plug-in architecture in Swift.

**Use Case**

An application, fx. a CLI, has a folder from where it's executed where plug-ins can be placed and will be loaded when the application starts.

**Requirements**

- Being able to define a protocol or a set of protocols that plug-ins
  must or can adhere to.
- Pure Swift.
- Introspect what protocols a given plug-in implements.
- Loaded dynamically when the application starts up.
- Communicate with delegate pattern.
- Plug-in developers should be able to import protocols, implement them, compile and place the binary in the plug-in folder.

**What I've tried**

I've used `Process`to start an executable where I can also add arguments.
But that doesn't satisfy my requirements.

I came across this [post](http://blog.pendowski.com/plugin-architecture-in-swift-ish/) of how it could be done, but that requires use of `NSBundle` and Objective-C so that's no good either.

I'm not really sure how to go about this. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you plan to have this work on Linux? What about the App Store?

Comment: @Kametrixom Linux is a goal. App Store is not a requirement.

Comment: Hi. Are you able to achieve this plug in architecture in Swift? This is what I need to work on right now. Any suggestions you have for me?

Answer (score 1):

Swift currently doesn't have a stable ABI so you can't rely on native interfaces yet. (This is expected to be resolved by Swift 4.)

I can think of two options for now, but both rely on defining some sort of a communication protocol between host and plug-in. You'll also have to implement your requirements (introspection of features, etc.) by yourself if you can't use Objective-C.

1. Lower to the C ABI. For every function you need, implement it on the called side in Swift with the `@convention(c)` annotation and declare it on the caller side in a header for external linkage. You won't be able to implement a function twice, so you should define a callback-based API that plug-ins register themselves into.
2. Define a (e.g., socket-based) communication protocol and write the Swift source files to be imported in every plug-in. Make the plug-ins executable which, upon launch by the host application, start the communication.

I personally prefer option 2 because it doesn't require mingling with linkers and such and you get the added bonus of defining Swift types and functions for the plug-in's use. Also, since the plug-in is a forked child, it can crash without affecting the host.